# Как сделать чтобы в телеграм боте после нажатия на кнопку клавиатуры отправлялся другой текст

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, telegram, бот

Есть бот с клавиатурой. Как сделать, чтобы на кнопках клавиатуры был текст "кнопка", а после нажатия отправлялся в чат текст со слешем "/кнопка"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для этого нужно обработать входящее событие с нажатия кнопки (гуглить можно по ключевому слову callback). работает по принципу входящего сообщения, только другой тип данных.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).